# Regex - Remove time from date

Tags: jquery, regex, datepicker

I would like to remove the time from a date. The date is generated through the platform I am working with and the time defaults to 12:00am. I would like to remove the time from the text as it is unecessary for what I am doing. How would I accomplish this with regex? Is this something I can use jQuery UI datepicker for possibly? I obviously don't know what I am doing with regex, as I find it pretty complicated.

HTML:

```
<span class="custom-date">
    Jun  2 2014 12:00AM
</span>
```

jQuery (That I have tried):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".custom-date").each(function(){
        var value = $(this).text().replace(/12:00AM/g,'');
        date = $.datepicker.formatDate(
            'mm-dd-yy', new Date(value));
        $(this).html(date);
    });
});
```

Comment: You need to make a substantial attempt to solve the problem before asking here.  Otherwise, it is a low quality question.

Comment: Why use a regex at all?  Once trimmed of whitespace the date is clearly just the first 11 characters - `var value = $(this).text().trim().substring(0, 11)`

Comment: @Alnitak - And what about if the month, day, or time changes?

Comment: @j08691 almost _any_ change to the format will likely require a code change - perhaps the only invariant is the space separating the fields, per your answer.

Comment: I guess with my limited experience, I thought a regex would be the best solution. Figures that jQuery has a function to deal with this.

Comment: @Phorden nope, jQuery is a DOM manipulation library, not a general date/string library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't need a regex, you can use:

```
$('span.custom-date').text($('span.custom-date').text().split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ') )
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/tHGDu/)**

Comment: consider using the function callback version of `.text` - it'll produce a cleaner implementation.

Comment: no, like this: `$(el).text(function(_, t) { return t.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ') })`

Comment: my mistake (re padding) - I was confusing it with languages with `split` functions that coalesce repeated separators.

Comment: @Alnitak - What am I looking for there?

Comment: The lack of `$(this).text()` inside the function - the existing text is automatically passed as a parameter so you don't have to retrieve it.

Comment: I see now that I should have used string manipulation in the first place. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you could also do something like:

```
var dt = $.trim($('span.custom-date').text());
var dtArr = dt.split(' ');
var withoutTime = jQuery.grep(dtArr, function( n, i ) {
  console.log(dtArr.length);
  return i < (dtArr.length - 1);
}).join(' ');
console.log(withoutTime);
```

or simply:

```
var dt = $.trim($('span.custom-date').text());
var dtArr = dt.split(' ');
var withoutTime = dtArr.pop();
console.log(dtArr.join(' '));
```